# How to fill a random position of a size 10 1D array with 1s and 0s the rest

Tags: c++

how i fill 10size 1d array randomly 1 and 0 the rest

like `0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0` or `0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0` or `0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0`

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    int x[10] = { 0, }, i;
    while (true)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            x[i] = rand() % 1 + 1;
            cout << x[i];
        }
        system("cls");
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

I don't want  `0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0` or `0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1`

Comment: Just use `rand()` once, to get the position of the `1`.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Trivial for you, not necessarily for a beginner.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen come on...

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry I'm studying with a double major I'm serious I can't see which part is wrong

Comment: @banna your code is obviously wrong. You set _each_ of the 10 array elements randomly to zero or to one. What you need is to set exactly _one_ of the 10 element to one. How would you do this with a pencil and a piece of paper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instatiate an array of int like `int x[10] = {};`, in this way you will get an array fill of zeros.
Than you can simply use `rand() % 10`, it will produce a random number in [0, 9], and it will be the position in the array where the 1 is:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int x[10] = {};
x[rand() % 10] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    cout << x[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are setting a new `1` every time your loop makes a lap. Eventually, you'll have all `1`:s.

- Either create a new zero-initialized array every loop *or* set the `1` back to `0` after you've printed the values in the array.
- `Sleep` is not a standard C++ function. Use `std::this_thread::sleep_for` and `std::chrono::milliseconds` instead.
- I also recommend using the new `<random>` library that was added in C++11:

Example setting it back to `0` after the result has been printed:

```
#include <array>     // std::array, std::size
#include <chrono>    // std::chrono::milliseconds
#include <iostream>
#include <random>    // std::mt19937, std::uniform_int_distribution
#include <thread>    // std::this_thread::sleep_for

auto& prng() {
     // Create a static seeded PRNG to use everywhere in the program
    thread_local std::mt19937 instance(std::random_device{}());
    return instance;
}

int main() {
    std::array<int, 10> x{};   // a nicer array

    // Create a distribution for your random numbers to get random numbers
    // in the range [0, 10)
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> dist(0, std::size(x) - 1); // [0, 9]

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) { // print 100 of these arrays
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        
        auto index = dist(prng()); // get a random index [0, 9]
        x[index] = 1;              // set the int at index to 1

        // print the result
        for(int v : x) std::cout << v;
        std::cout << '\n';

        x[index] = 0;              // set it back to 0
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rrf6e1bT8)

Comment: Thank you so much, but my level is low, so my professor won't admit this answer. But it's been a lot of study.

Comment: @banna That's perfectly fine :-) I hope you accept Nicholas' answer (there is a grayed out check mark beside the answer) since that is what helped you to solve it.